# How to count the files that are sent by form and apply a consecutive to them?

Tags: python, html, flask

[FLASK] Greetings. I hope you can help me with the following: How could you create a counter of all the files that are sent by form, and then assign a consecutive number to each file?. Example: LOT_image_001, LOT_image_002 etc... Thanks in advance.

This my code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './Files PDF'

@app.route("/")
def upload_file():
 return render_template('form.html')

@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
 counter = 0
 root_path = './Files PDF'
 if request.method == 'POST':
  counter = counter + 1
  f = request.files['file']
  filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
  final_name = "LOT_{}".format(filename)
  os.rename(root_path + '\\' + filename, root_path + '\\' + final_name)
  return render_template('form.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run("0.0.0.0",8000,threaded=True,debug=True)
```

This is my form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    
  <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is used to upload a file to a folder and rename it with a counter. The file name is in the format `LOT_<filename>_[counter].<extension>`
Example: `LOT_something_001.pdf`

Using a database to save the counter is recommended because it is easy to track counter parameters.
But if you want to use this code without a database, you can use the code below to get the last number of the file in the folder.

! Keep in mind that the file name must be in the format `LOT_<filename>_[counter].<extension>` and the counter is **3 digits**.
Use underline `_` for the storage folder name instead `space`

app.py

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from werkzeug.datastructures import  FileStorage

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = './Files_PDF'

@app.route("/")
def upload_file():
 return render_template('form.html')

def _get_last_number():
    '''Get the last number of the file in the folder, if there is no file, return 0.
    format: LOT_<filename>_000.<extension>'''
    last_number = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']):
        if filename.startswith('LOT_'):
            try:
              _filename = filename.split('_')[-1]
              number = int(_filename.split('.')[0])
            except ValueError:
                continue
            if number > last_number:
                last_number = number
    return last_number


@app.route("/upload", methods=['POST'])
def uploader():
 if request.method == 'POST':
  f = request.files['file']
  filename = secure_filename(f.filename)

  # get the last number of the file in the folder
  counter = _get_last_number() + 1

  # final name of the file with the format LOT_<filename>_[counter].<extension>
  final_name = "LOT_{}".format(filename.split('.')[0] + "_{:03d}.".format(counter) + filename.split('.')[1])

  # save the file in the folder with the final name
  f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], final_name)) # save the file in the folder


  return render_template('form.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
 app.run("0.0.0.0",8000,threaded=True,debug=True)
```

Comment: It works perfectly. @Shekhrox I'm very grateful for helping me.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote the answer because I don't have enough reputation yet. I will reply as soon as I can. But your answer 100% solved my question. I hope it can be of use to the community.